# Snap next autorefresh is n/a - why?

Tags: snap

I have been facing recently an issue with snap auto-update. My Ubuntu 20.04 is prompting me for a Software update but when I click update (snapd, IDEA Community) it pops up with

```
Unable to update snapd: status-code=409 kind=snap-change-conflict message=snap "snapd" has "auto-refresh" change in progress
```

so I am basically unable to update these two (the same message goes for IntelliJ) ...

When I checked my snap config it says:

```
...@...:~$ snap refresh --time
timer: 4:00-7:00,19:00-22:10
last: 3 days ago, at 05:41 CET
next: n/a
```

Why does it say "next: n/a" ?? I even tried to set the timer but even tho it executed successfully the command above returns still the same result .. next: n/a

```
sudo snap set system refresh.timer=fri,10:00-12:00
```

And the refresh --list returns:

```
...@...:~$ snap refresh --list
Name                     Version  Rev    Publisher   Notes
intellij-idea-community  2020.3   267    jetbrains✓  classic
snapd                    2.48.1   10492  canonical✓  snapd
```

any idea what is going on pls?

**EDIT1:**

snap changes result:

```
...@...:~$ snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn                     Ready                   Summary
54   Done    4 days ago, at 05:41 CET  yesterday at 10:31 CET  Auto-refresh 4 snaps
55   Done    yesterday at 09:57 CET    yesterday at 09:57 CET  Refresh "android-studio" snap
56   Done    yesterday at 09:58 CET    yesterday at 09:58 CET  Refresh all snaps: no updates
57   Done    yesterday at 10:00 CET    yesterday at 10:00 CET  Change configuration of "core" snap
58   Done    yesterday at 19:04 CET    yesterday at 19:05 CET  Auto-refresh snap "snapd"
```

sudo snap abort:

```
...@...:~$ sudo snap abort 54
error: cannot abort change 54 with nothing pending
```

Answer (score 0):

The refresh of these applications could be stuck, which would prevent new refresh attempts to start. Type this into your terminal: `snap changes`. So long as you have a refresh taking place in some state, you might see something like:

```
ID   Status   Spawn                     Ready  Summary
99   Undoing  yesterday at 09:15 +0900  -      Auto-refresh snap "{name}"
```

From there you can try to abort the in-progress update with:

```
sudo snap abort 99
```

Be sure to change `99` to whatever value you see in `ID`.

Once this is done, you may be able to perform a `sudo snap refresh` to manually refresh all of your snaps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey man, thx for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work :( see my edit pls for more details